# Angular $watch object and get property name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to `$watch` an object for changes on any of its properties and, when any of them changes, get its name (apart from `newValue` and `oldValue`).

Is that possible?

Comment: Haven't you tried yet?

Comment: Object out of scope ?

Comment: What exactly is your use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is two years old but I just ran into the same issue and I thought i'd share my solution to it. Back in the 1.2 version you used to be able to access the changed property by referencing `this.exp` in the watch function, but that was deprecated presumably for performance reasons. The easiest way to get the changed property is to loop through the new and old objects and compare the values by property name.

```
$scope.settings = {
    'opt1' : 'something',
    'opt2' : 'something else',
    'opt3' : 'another something',
};

$scope.$watchCollection('settings', function(newObj, oldObj) {

    // Loop through new object and compare
    angular.forEach(newObj, function(val, key) {
        if(newObj[key] !== oldObj[key]) {

            // settings[key] changed
        }
    });

}, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible - the only information you get is the new and previous value of an watched object.

You can tell that by looking at the Angular digest loop implementation:

```
// I ommited most of the code, leaving only the relevant part

if ((watchers = current.$$watchers)) {
  while (/* iterate over watchers */) {
    // Compare the current value with the last known value
    if ((value = watch.get(current)) !== (last = watch.last)) {
      // Notify the callback - only the whole values (new and last) are supplied.
      watch.fn(value, ((last === initWatchVal) ? value : last), current);
    }
}
```

---

You could manually enumerate object properties and compare them, or you could use some third party library for that. Quick NPM search returned this: [deep-diff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff) (it is available through bower as well). If you do opt to use it, it could look like:

```
$scope.$watch('watchedObject', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  var differences = diff(newValue, oldValue);
  // now inspect the differences array to see if there are any
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Watching an object is not possible, unless you know the variable name in the `$scope`.

Say you have an object you want to watch at `$scope.myobject`. You will iterate over the object properties:

```
var objprops = []
angular.foreach(myobject, function(value, key) {
    objprops.push("myobject." + key);
});
objexpr = "[" + objprops.join(",") + "]";
//objexpr will be something like "[myobject.a, myobject.b, myobject.c, ...]"
```

Then you watch over this array:

```
$scope.$watch(objexpr, function(newv, oldv){
    //do iteration here
});
```

**The big caveat here** is that, to detect the changed values, you must iterate the `newv` array against the `oldv` array and remember `objprops` to know which field actually changed.

It's not clean... at all